# How to add the UIButton present in storyboard to the top of AVPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, splash-screen

I am doing the implementation of video splash similar to Uber in my application. I had added two buttons in the storyboard at the bottom part with equal spacing in storyboard. Now i am adding AVPlayer to play a video present in NSBundle. While running the application the video is playing but i cant see my buttons at the bottom part. Why it is happening? Please suggest..

```
   - (void)createVideoPlayer {

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"welcome_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    self.player.volume = PLAYER_VOLUME;

    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    playerLayer.videoGravity = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.layer.bounds;
    [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    [self.player play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayDidEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.player.currentItem];
}

- (void)moviePlayDidEnd:(NSNotification*)notification{

    AVPlayerItem *item = [notification object];
    [item seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [self.player play];
}
```

The screenshot of buttons in storyboard:
[image]

The output in simulator:

[image]

You can see buttons are missing and **Note: constraints of these buttons are correct and i can see them in every preview...**

Comment: Try `bringSubviewToFront` with your button after adding avplayer.

Comment: how to do this to UIButton in storyboard?

Comment: try frame of that player.

Comment: @JessicaRoot You need to write code for that after adding `avplayer`.

Comment: okkey So you mean to create an outlet for that buttons and bringsubviewtofront?

Comment: @JessicaRoot Yes that was i'm saying.

Comment: Thanks I got it .... If you post an answer i can accept that.... Please do support my question.

Comment: @JessicaRoot I have put my comment as answer, as you mentioned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `bringSubviewToFront` to bring your `Button` outlet front and visible on `AVPlayer` after adding `AVPlyer` instance in your view.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:buttonOutlet];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling bringSubviewToFront on the button after you've added the avplayer.